# Forest plot facet grid comparing regression model coefficients from multiple models

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap, r-forestplot, modelsummary

I am currently working with 30 datasets with the same column names, but different numeric data. I need to apply a linear mixed model and a generalised linear model to every instance of the dataset and plot the resulting fixed effect coefficients on a forest plot.

The data is currently structured as follows (using the same dataset for every list element for simplicity):

```
library(lme4)

data_list <- list()

# There's definitely a better way of doing this through lapply(), I just can't figure out how
for (i in 1:30){
     data_list[[i]] <- tibble::as_tibble(mtcars) # this would originally load different data at every instance
}

compute_model_lmm <- function(data){
     lmer("mpg ~ hp + disp + drat + (1|cyl)", data = data)
}

result_list_lmm <- lapply(data_list, compute_model_lmm)
```

What I am currently doing is

```
library(modelsummary)

modelplot(result_list_lmm)+
     facet_wrap(~model) #modelplot() takes arguments/functions from ggplot2
```

[image: Plot of linear mixed model's beta coefficients using facet_wrap(~model) (throughout the whole list of datasets]

which takes an awful amount of time, but it works.

Now, I would like to compare another model on the same plot, as in

```
compute_model_glm <- function(data){
     glm("mpg ~ hp + disp + drat + cyl", data = data)
}

result_list_glm <- lapply(data_list, compute_model_glm)

modelplot(list(result_list_lmm[[1]], result_list_glm[[1]]))
```

[image: Plot of comparison between a single lmm and glm]

but for every instance of the plot.

How do I specify it to `modelplot()`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "I want to compare another model on the same plot but with the grid structure"? It's not clear to me exactly what the resulting plot should look like.

Comment: Sorry if it was unclear, hope it's better now

Comment: Still not sure. Do you want a plot like the one in my answer below?

Comment: Yeah, that is what I meant

Comment: OK, great! Then please accept that answer if it does what you need, or explain why it remains inadequate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `modelplot` function gives you a few basic ways of plotting coefficients and intervals (check the `facet` argument, for example).

However, the real power of the function comes by using the `draw=FALSE` argument. In that case, `modelplot` does the hard job of giving you the estimates in a convenient data frame, with all the renaming, robust standard errors, and other utilities of the `modelplot` function. Then, you can use that data frame to do the plotting yourself with `ggplot2` for infinite customization.

```r
library(modelsummary)
library(ggplot2)

results_lm <- lapply(1:10, function(x) lm(hp ~ mpg, data = mtcars)) |>
    modelplot(draw = FALSE) |>
    transform("Function" = "lm()")
results_glm <- lapply(1:10, function(x) glm(hp ~ mpg, data = mtcars)) |>
    modelplot(draw = FALSE) |>
    transform("Function" = "glm()")
results <- rbind(results_lm, results_glm) 

head(results)
          term   model estimate std.error conf.low conf.high Function
1  (Intercept) Model 1 324.0823   27.4333  268.056  380.1086     lm()
3  (Intercept) Model 2 324.0823   27.4333  268.056  380.1086     lm()
5  (Intercept) Model 3 324.0823   27.4333  268.056  380.1086     lm()
7  (Intercept) Model 4 324.0823   27.4333  268.056  380.1086     lm()
9  (Intercept) Model 5 324.0823   27.4333  268.056  380.1086     lm()
11 (Intercept) Model 6 324.0823   27.4333  268.056  380.1086     lm()

ggplot(results, aes(y = term, x = estimate, xmin = conf.low, xmax = conf.high)) +
    geom_pointrange(aes(color = Function), position = position_dodge(width = .5)) +
    facet_wrap(~model)
```

[image]

Comment: Just a heads up, I was using `lmer()` in my example, not `lm()` (I don't think it changes anything except for the formula)